# three.js shadermaterial not working at all

Tags: three.js, shader

I've been fiddling around with three.js a bit, and im stumped when it comes to `THREE.ShaderMaterial`. it started out with copy/pasting directly from the example, shown here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_normalmap

i copied it into a function that just returns the material. it wouldnt work (error, i'll get to the specifics later), so i removed all the uniforms that had been set and went for a complete blank material. just to see if the same error would still show.

so here's my code:

```
var testmaterial = function(params){
    var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
    var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

    var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms};
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );

    return material;
};
```

nothing fancy you'd say, and i'd agree, however, the browser seems to disagree. here's the error i just cant seem to get rid of:

error X6077: texld/texldb/texldp/dsx/dsy instructions with r# as source cannot be used inside dynamic conditional 'if' blocks, dynamic conditional subroutine calls, or loop/rep with break*.

does anyone have the slightest clue on what i'm doing wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shader you chose, namely `normalmap`, requires some input uniforms to be set. 
If you look at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r68/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js#L595 you will see the variables that are null:

```
    "tDisplacement": { type: "t", value: null },
    "tDiffuse"     : { type: "t", value: null },
    "tCube"        : { type: "t", value: null },
    "tNormal"      : { type: "t", value: null },
    "tSpecular"    : { type: "t", value: null },
    "tAO"          : { type: "t", value: null },
```

So either you need to set these or since you are just fiddling around try another simple shader that does not require inputs. Seems that most others do not require input uniforms to be set.

**EDIT:**

You also need to compute the models' tangents.
But for that you need to use a different pattern.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 50, 50);
geometry.computeTangents();

var material = myShaderMaterial({
    //enableAO          : 0,
    enableDiffuse       : 1,
    //enableSpecular    : 0,
    //enableReflection  : 0,
    enableDisplacement  : 1,

    tDisplacement       : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/planets/earthbump1k.jpg'),
    tDiffuse            : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/planets/earthbump1k.jpg'),
    //tCube             : planet.maps.planet.
    tNormal             : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/planets/earthbump1k.jpg'),
    //tSpecular         : planet.maps.planet.
    //tAO               : planet.maps.planet.
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Comment: when i give it uniforms, it will give the same error, and it will not show the material.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: output: http://77.174.100.75/problem.html , 
script: http://77.174.100.75/problem.js

Comment: just a note: dont use such huge numbers. Your lights' distance is way way too big. So is your cameras' far plane. Bring them down to 1000.

Comment: done, didnt think it mattered for an example though.

Comment: the 'done' is for the tangents or for the numbers? the tangents did not work?

Comment: the numbers. problem still persists

Comment: apologies, didnt notice. adjusted and the problem still persists.

Comment: Yes but the error know changed to `WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: uniform3fv: invalid size`.

Comment: Can you link with the non-minified version of three.js so I can see in the debugger the line the error is coming from?

Comment: my god, i really lack perception today, so what does that mean? the texture is too big? adjusted.

Comment: I think that it is referring to the fact that uniform3fv means "set a uniform from this array of 3 floats" and you dont do that.

Comment: actually, im still getting the same error in firefox. chrome does show the uniform3fv error, but lets focus om chrome first, since that's the one that changed. which means progress!

Comment: Can you link with the non-minified version of three.js so I can see in the debugger the line the error is coming from?

Comment: it is linked to the adjusted html file, but here's the link nonetheless: http://77.174.100.75/js/three.js

Comment: i have now, the problem persists.

Comment: Wow, after some serious debugging ... found it. Add `lights: true` to your parameters variable in problem.js.