# THREE.WebGLProgram Error X6077

Tags: compiler-errors, three.js, webgl, shader

I'm getting an error when using the predefined `normalmap` shader from `THREE.ShaderLib`. My material shows up, but displacement map is not applied. If i set `uDisplacementScale` or `uDisplacementBias` uniforms, it get's applied for the complete object and not only the parts that are marked in my displacement texture.

Here is my code:

```
var geometry = // some geometry ...
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
geometry.computeTangents();

var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["normalmap"];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

uniforms[ "enableAO" ].value = true;
uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = true;
uniforms[ "enableSpecular" ].value = true;
uniforms[ "enableReflection" ].value = false;
uniforms[ "enableDisplacement" ].value = true;

uniforms[ "tDisplacement" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/tex_DISP.png" );
uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/tex_COLOR.png" );
uniforms[ "tNormal" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/tex_NRM.png" );
uniforms[ "tSpecular" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/tex_SPEC.png" );
uniforms[ "tAO" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/tex_OCC.png" );

var shaderParams = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights: true, fog: false };
var material  = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( shaderParams );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

And here is the error:

```
(63,12): error X6077: texld/texldb/texldp/dsx/dsy instructions with r# as source cannot
be used inside dynamic conditional 'if' blocks, dynamic conditional subroutine calls, 
or loop/rep with break*.

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with 
 default
  flags.
  Retrying with 
avoid flow control
.
```

Do the the statement types described in the error message apply to shader code, or to the point of code from where I initialize my `THREE.ShaderMaterial`? Or are they caused by another error, that has nothing to do with the one described?

Comment: possible duplicate of [three.js shadermaterial not working at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889688/three-js-shadermaterial-not-working-at-all)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889688. Exactly same problem.

Comment: I had already taken a look and I think my code acts pretty much like the code provided in the answer - but still I get the error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @gaitat - The important things in the other post were using `computeTangents()` and specifying `lights : true` in the ShaderMaterial parameters. These changes are already done in my code. Still, the error occurs. Any further ideas, what could be wrong?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or post your code somewhere?

Comment: Ah I got my mistake. I fergot to have enough width and height segments in my geometry. Displacement mapping does only work with enough individual segments set in your geometry data. However, the error mentioned above still occurs. I guess I should just ignore it, as the result looks good now. - http://jsfiddle.net/aeh09pda/11/

Comment: I dont get any errors on Chrome (latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the normalmap shader doesnt add additional vertices for applying the displacement mapping - it only applies height to existing vertices.

So, the failure was, that I didnt provide enough vertices in my mesh. The solution was to use a more detailed geometry. For example, the predefined Geometries in three.js have segments parameters, which allow the user to subdivide parts of the geometry into multiple segments and thus create more than just the contour vertices in the resulting mesh.

This will not work with displacement map:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100);
```

This generates enough vertices for displacement map to work:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100,100,100);
```

So, in the end, Error X6077 still occurs and was not responsible for the failing displacement mapping. Indeed, it does not seem to occur in some browsers, like Chrome, at all.